# Swift "nearly matches defaulted requirement"

Tags: swift, warnings, protocols

I have a protocol like this, with some default implementation for the methods:

```
public protocol BusinessModelTransformable {
    func modelId() -> ModelID
    func asModelElement(bModel: BusinessModel) -> ModelElement
}
public extension BusinessModelTransformable {
    func modelId() -> ModelID { UUID().uuidString }
    func asModelElement(bModel: BusinessModel) -> ModelElement {
        ModelElement(bModel: bModel, id: self.modelId())
    }
}
```

In another file (of another package if that matters), I do add a conformance to the protocol to a struct, but I don't want the default implement, so I provide my own:

```
extension ImpDesc: BusinessModelTransformable {
    public func modelId() -> ModelID { self.id.uuidString }
    public func asModelElement(bModel: BusinessModel) -> ModelElement {
        ExtendedModelElement(bModel:    bModel,
                             id:        self.id.uuidString,
                             payload:   self)
    }
}
```

I get this warning:

> Instance method 'asModelElement(bModel:)' nearly matches defaulted requirement 'asModelElement(bModel:)' of protocol 'BusinessModelTransformable'

**only** for the `asModelElement` method.

- Why this warning, as this is to me a perfectly valid pattern ?
- Why **only for the second method** ?
- how to get rid of that warning () ?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. What are the types used in your `BusinessModelTransformable` requirement? Namely, `ModelID`, `BusinessModel` and `ModelElement`? Is there a chance you have the same types in both modules?

Comment: _Why this warning_ because while the declarations look the same there is some difference between them and as mentioned we need more information to understand that because the difference should have something to do with BusinessModel and/or ModelElement. _Why only for the second method_, because there is no ambiguity with the first one!, _how to get rid of that warning_, we need more information as mentioned

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : "while the declarations look the same there is some difference between them " - Thanks that was it !!! character per character, they are exactly the same, but BusinessModel is defined as a protocol in a package, and as a class somewhere else. And I realised that trying to make the "minimal reproducible code". So many thanks to both of you. If you want to formulate an answer in this direction, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written by @Joakim Danielson in his comment (many thanks): "while the declarations look the same there is some difference between them", there was indeed a name conflict that was leading to the problem.

Lessons learnt, when the compiler tells you something, that might very well be true.